Looking to replace Indirect function to pull dynamic ranges
I've created a dynamic range formula which shows as below:
=CONCATENATE("AC SalesRawData!",SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,C1,4),"1",""),":",SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,C2,4),"1",""))

Which gives me the range output "AC SalesRawData!CQ:DS"
I'm then referencing this range in an vlookup using Indirect as shown below:
=VLOOKUP($A7,INDIRECT(C$3),'AC Sales Conversion'!C$4,FALSE)

The issue being, there are thousands of this formula pulling individual pieces of data. I don't want this to recalculate all the time as it keeps kicking errors or returning #REF!.
Is there a way to replace the indirect function but get the same result?

If you have access to MS365, then may be you can use the 3D-Reference feature available with HSTACK() or VSTACK() or TOCOL(). You could make use of it. I have used the same concept in the following linked answer

Instead of building a dynamic array it seems like XLOOKUP, FILTER or an index/match approach on a static array would be easier. If you must have a dynamic array (the previous comment may help) please edit your question to add this context.
